# D3 vertical line graph

Tags: d3.js

I have a line (& area) graph which works ok, when horizontal. But I really need it to be vertical, to stand up. I have tried all kinds of changes to the existing code. Mostly with some strange results.

Here’s the code (modified it a bit). Is there a way to change it to make the graph vertical?:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([1, itemCount]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, maxValue]).rangeRound([height, 0]);

// Set up linar x and y axis.
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(10);
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(2).orient("left");

// Line graph.
line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
        return x(d.x);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
        return y(d.y);
    });

    // Create SVG element.
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    // X-Axis, to bottom.
    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(1," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    //Y-Axis
    svg.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(40, 1)")
        .call(yAxis);

    // Horizontal axis guide lines.
    svg.selectAll("line.y")
        .data(y.ticks(5))
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y1", y)
        .attr("y2", y)
        .style("stroke", "#000000")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1);

    // Vertical axis guide lines.
    svg.selectAll("line.x")
        .data(y.ticks(5))
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("x1", x)
        .attr("x2", x)
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", this.heightInside - pushDown)
        .style("stroke", "#000000")
        .style("stroke-opacity", 0.1);

    // Set up domains. Nice ensures the domains ends on nice round values.
    x.domain([dataValues[0].x, dataValues[dataValues.length - 1].x]).nice();
    y.domain([d3.min(dataValues, function (d) { return (d.y); }),
              d3.max(dataValues, function (d) { return (d.y); })])
      .nice();

    // Draw line on graph.
    svg.append("svg:path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line(dataValues))
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return colors[i]; });

    // Marks.
    svg.selectAll("circle_" + i)
        .data(dataValues)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return _this.colors[i]; })
        .attr("r", 4)
        .attr('cx', function (d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr('cy', function (d) { return y(d.y); });
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data or a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Basically all you have to do is swap the x and y coordinates for the generated elements.

Comment: Took me some time to figure out how to make JSFiddle work, but when I had made an example in JSfiddle I figured out how to make it vertical.

Comment: @Rune I know this is an old post, but do you happen to have the gist or some similar code that got it to work?  The question still hasn't been answered and I'm interested as well